# Array from function to another with dynamic allocating (C)

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory

I'm trying to write the following code that calculates the moving average.
In "main.c" file i call 2 functions of "movingAVG.h":
The function initAVG() create an array and initialize all element with 0, with this function i choose the number of saples to use for average .
The function getAVG() take the array, replace the oldest sample with the newest and return the calculated average.
I need to pass the array from initAVG to getAVG using the pointer array duality property but i'm not able to do that, i'm new to C. What i'm doing wrong?
Any help would be really appreciated. Many thanks!

```
/* ========================================
 *
MEDIA MOBILE.
 *
 * ========================================
*/

#include "project.h"

uint8 start=0;
uint8 iy; //sample's vector index
uint32 sum=0;
uint32 avg;
uint32 *ptrSamples;

void initAVG(nSample)
{
    uint8 i=0;
    uint32 Samples[nSample];
    ptrSamples = Samples;

    while (i<=nSample)
    {
        Samples[nSample]=0;
        i++;
    }
    start=1;
}

uint32 getAVG(uint8 nSample,uint32 lastvalue)
{
    if (iy<=nSample && start==1)
    {
        sum -= ptrSamples[iy];
        ptrSamples[iy] = lastvalue;
        sum += ptrSamples[iy];
        avg = sum / (nSample + 1);
        if (iy<nSample)
        {
            iy++;
        }else {iy = 0;}
    }
    return avg;
}

/* [] END OF FILE */
```

EDIT:
I tried to use dynamic memory allocation with malloc() for the array but it doesn't work. What's wrong?
Does the allocated memory with malloc() survive exiting from initAVG() function?

```
#include "project.h"
#include "malloc.h"

uint8 start=0;
uint8 iy; //sample's vector index
uint32 sum=0;
uint32 avg;
uint8 nSample;
uint32* ptrSamples;

void initAVG(numberOfSample)
{
    uint8 i=0;
    nSample=numberOfSample;
    ptrSamples = malloc((nSample+1)*sizeof(uint32)); 

    while (i<=nSample)
    {
        ptrSamples[i]=0;
        i++;
    }
    start=1;
}

uint32 getAVG(uint32 lastvalue)
{
    if (iy<=nSample && start==1)
    {
        sum -= ptrSamples[iy];
        ptrSamples[iy] = lastvalue;
        sum += ptrSamples[iy];
        avg = sum / (nSample + 1);
        if (iy<nSample)
        {
            iy++;
        }else {iy = 0;}
    }
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: It looks like all you have to do is make Samples global.

Comment: In initAVG, you set ptrSamples to be a pointer to a local variable and then use that pointer in getAVG. That's illegal. Try the mnistic's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating array Samples inside function initAVG(), And you are storing an address of the first element of the array in the pointer ptrSamples.

But if you are calling these functions from main(), in the following order as

```
initAVG();
getAVG();
```

The lifetime of Samples is only for the time the function initAVG() is executing. After execution of the function, the array will not be there in memory. But the pointer is still pointing to same memory location.

So please make the array global or assign dynamic memory for the array.

Comment: If i declare the array Sample[nSample] as global, i cannot use the variable nSample for its lenght
`uint32 Samples[nSample];` not allowed

Answer (score 0):

It works! 
I'm working on a development board and the problem was only an insufficient heap size in settings. Increasing it, the code works well. 
Really thanks to everyone!

```
#include "project.h"
#include "malloc.h"

uint8 start=0;
uint8 iy; //sample's vector index
uint32 sum=0;
uint32 avg;
uint8 nSample;
uint32* ptrSamples;     //dichiaro un puntatore ad un uint32 chiamato ptrSamples

void initAVG(numberOfSample)
{
    uint8 i=0;
    nSample=numberOfSample;
    ptrSamples = malloc((nSample+1)*sizeof(uint32));      //allòco 255 celle il cui indirizzo della prima sarà memorizzato nel puntatore ptrSamples

    while (i<=nSample)
    {
        ptrSamples[i]=0;    //sfruttando la dualità puntatore-vettore estraggo l'i-esimo valore del vettore corrispondente al puntatore
        i++;
    }
    start=1;
}

uint32 getAVG(uint32 lastvalue)
{
    if (iy<=nSample && start==1)
    {
        sum -= ptrSamples[iy];  
        ptrSamples[iy] = lastvalue;
        sum += ptrSamples[iy];
        avg = sum / (nSample + 1);
        if (iy<nSample)
        {
            iy++;
        }else {iy = 0;}
    }
    return avg;
}
```